# C# Как получить строку без шрифтов?

Tags: c#, шрифты

Есть строка

```
string text = "     ";
```

как из нее получить оригинальний текст без шрифтов ?

вместо

будет

ana tetyana ana tetyana ana tetyana

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно, вам подойдёт одна из форм нормализации:

```
var text = "     ";
// text.Length = 65

text = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD);
// text.Length = 35
```

`FormKC` тоже даёт длину 35.

Ссылки на то, что такое нормализация: [подробно на английском](http://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html), [чуть-чуть на русском](https://habr.com/post/45489/).