# C# Как получить текст строки без шрифтов?

Tags: c#, шрифты

Есть строка

```
string text = "ᎯᎽᎯ ᏦᎾᏉᏕ";
```

как из нее получить оригинальний текст без шрифтов ?

вместо

**ᎯᎽᎯ ᏦᎾᏉᏕ**

будет

**AYA KOVS**

Comment: вообще `string text = "ᎯᎽᎯ ᏦᎾᏉᏕ";` не содержит информацию о шрифтах, у вас видимо изначально шрифт в выводимом контроле изменен.

Comment: Откуда берется текст?

Comment: Можете попробовать использовать скрытый компонент, функциями которого измените шрифт вашего текста. А вообще, я не совсем понял вашего вопроса. Вы в переменную типа `string` записываете форматированный текст с измененным шрифтом. По идее он должен вывестись стандартным вариантом, т.е. очистит его. Что Вы имеете в виде `вместо` и будет`?

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/831403/184217

Comment: Нет, это не дубликат. В данном тексте нет комбинирующих символов.

Comment: Наткнулся на такое: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50534900/5045688

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это не шрифты, это похожие на латиницу символы других языков. Обычно такое используется для создания всяких замудренно выглядящих(fancy) имен в инстаграме и прочих соцсетях.

Единственный тут вариант - выдрать откуда-то или составить вручную словарь, да заменить по нему, например так:

```
string text = "ᎯᎽᎯ ᏦᎾᏉᏕ";

var dictionary = new Dictionary<char, char>()
{
    { 'Ꭿ', 'A' },
    { 'Ꮍ', 'Y' },
    { ' ', ' ' },
    { 'Ꮶ', 'K' },
    { 'Ꮎ', 'O' },
    { 'Ꮙ', 'V' },
    { 'Ꮥ', 'S' },

};

var builder = new StringBuilder(text);
for (int i = 0; i < builder.Length; i++)
{
    builder[i] = dictionary[builder[i]];
}

var result = builder.ToString();
```